# Receive push notification in Google Glass

Tags: android, push-notification, google-glass, google-cloud-messaging, gdk

I would like to receive notifications in Google Glass (in my Android smartphone I can do this trough Google Cloud Messaging), but in Glass, Google Play Services are not available...

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google Play Services is not available on Glass, you will need to use socket or bluetooth programming to establish a Glass connection with your phone, from which you can receive notifications from your web server.

At the very least, the Mirror API can start your Glassware using the OPEN_URI menu item. This works in combination with the ACTION_VIEW action and a `data android:scheme` that matches the OPEN_URI payload.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! what is the best option for you? Is there any example of do this through Mirror API?

Comment: Alternatively, you can check out [Notification Sync](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/notification-sync), which lets received Android notifications to also be sent to the Glass timeline.

Comment: But I need to receive the message inside the application, not on the Glass timeline :(

Answer (score 0):

The mirror api (server-side) is an alternative to forward the notification as Card to the Glass

Comment: But, with mirror api I can create cards on the Timeline... I want to receive notifications inside any app, is it possible?